# Filter crashes by custom keys

Tags: google-fabric

I've added custom key via `[CrashlyticsKit setObjectValue:@"free" forKey:@"user_type"];`. 
Can I somehow filter out only those crashes which had this custom value? Also, can I get a number of crashes for this key? I know I can use search, but it's not very convenient.

Thanks.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Currently search is the only option for this, but we're looking at improvements to make in this area.